# Imports work when using installed Python package but not in source code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

I am trying to wrap my head around this ImportError. I created a Python script, packaged it up and uploaded it to PyPi. When I import that package and run it, everything works well. However, when I try to run the source code of my Python script, I get this error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

```
proj
|---src
|    |---package_name
|    |    |---__init__.py
|    |    |---car.py
|    |    |---func.py
```

In class.py, I import functions from func.py like so: `from .func import *`. This causes the error when I try to run `python3 class.py`. What I can't understand is why this doesn't cause any issues when I install the package from Pypi, import it into another Python file, and use the class there.

Comment: Try to use this: `from func import *`

Comment: I'm getting the same ModuleError. Do you think it could be because I only uploaded the package into test.pypi and not pypi? I've read somewhere that module imports are treated differently depending on whether or not they're on pypi, but I don't know how it works with different modules in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Well, python does not lie, there is no known parent package - you must tell python that the script you are trying to run is part of a package. Try to `cd` to the *parent* of the `package_name` directory then issue:

```
python3 -m package_name.car # note no py and the -m 'module' switch
```

Aside: did you name your module class?? That can lead to nasty surprises - **never** use python reserved keywords for module/package/variable names (edit: that was corrected in current OP)

Comment: Oh that's a bad example I used. I didn't name it class and I just changed my example.
My files are all inside a package and I was successfully able to upload it. I tried the command you posted inside my package_name directory and I get: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

I read that I'm not really using it as a package if I just run it as a script. Is the command you posted the way to tell python that I'm trying to run a script that's part of a package?

Comment: Also, would there be problems if one of the classes has the same name as the package name?

Comment: Is the command you posted the way to tell python that I'm trying to run a script that's part of a package? -> yes

Comment: Oops I meant cd to the _parent_ of the parent package - see edits @FromTheEast

Comment: Also, would there be problems if one of the classes has the same name as the package name? – > no but may be not good style - unlike java python modules are not one to one to public classes